# Swift Sprite Kit Camera Movement

Tags: ios, swift, camera, sprite-kit

I made a Camera in Sprite Kit focusing on a *SKSpriteNode*.

There is a great Document by Apple: [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html)

However, the camera as it now is follows the SKSpriteNode immediately, while I want to have a little leeway.

For e.g. the *SKSpriteNode* moves up and down after a touch is made, the camera follows the *SKSpriteNode* slowly from its origin point, and the maximum distance Height for the *SKSpriteNode* is half of the screen, and when the *SKSpriteNode* stands still, the camera and the *SKSpriteNode* move again to their origin point.

**Also** the PhysicBody's of the Nodes behave strangely, moving away from its actual image. How can I fix that ?

Here is my Code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var Player: SKSpriteNode!

var Platform0: SKSpriteNode!
var Platform1: SKSpriteNode!
var Platform2: SKSpriteNode!
var Platform3: SKSpriteNode!
var Platform4: SKSpriteNode!
var Platform5: SKSpriteNode!

var World: SKNode!
var Camera: SKNode!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.1)

    self.World = SKNode()
    self.World.name = "World"
    addChild(self.World)
    self.Camera = SKNode()
    self.Camera.name = "Camera"
    self.World.addChild(self.Camera)

    SpawnPlatforms()
    SpawnPlayer()
}

func SpawnPlatforms() {

    Platform0 = SKSpriteNode (color: SKColor.greenColor(), size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width , height: 25))
    Platform0.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: 40)
    Platform0.zPosition = 1

    Platform0.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:Platform0.size)
    Platform0.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    Platform0.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    Platform0.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    Platform0.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

    Platform0.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Platform0Category
    Platform0.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PlayerCategory
    Platform0.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PlayerCategory

    World.addChild(Platform0)

    /// All other Platforms declared as the same above

}

func SpawnPlayer(){

    var Player1:SKTexture!
    var Player2:SKTexture!

    var Animation:SKAction!
    var AnimationRepeat:SKAction!

    Player1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Image.png")
    Player1.filteringMode = .Nearest
    Player2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Image2.png")
    Player2.filteringMode = .Nearest

    Animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([Player1,Player2], timePerFrame: 0.5)
    AnimationRepeat = SKAction.repeatActionForever(Animation)

    Player = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "Image.png")
    Player.size = CGSize(width: 64, height: 64)
    Player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: 80)
    Player.zPosition = 2

    Player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:CGSize(width: 35, height: 50))
    Player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    Player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    Player.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    Player.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    Player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -0.1)

    Player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PlayerCategory
    Player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Platform0Category
    Player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Platform0Category | Platform1Category | Platform2Category | Platform3Category | Platform4Category | Platform5Category

    Player.runAction(AnimationRepeat)
    World.addChild(Player)

}

override func didFinishUpdate() {

    Camera.position = CGPoint(x: Player.position.x, y: Player.position.y)
    self.centerOnNode(Camera)

}

func centerOnNode(node: SKNode) {

    let cameraPositionInScene: CGPoint = node.scene!.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: World)

    node.parent!.position = CGPoint(x:node.parent!.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x, y:node.parent!.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y)

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of directly declaring the position in centeronnode, use SKAction moveTo.

It has a duration value.

Replace your old centerOnNode func with:

```
func centerOnNode(node: SKNode) {

    let cameraPositionInScene: CGPoint = node.scene!.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: World)

    node.parent!..runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x:node.parent!.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x, y:node.parent!.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y), duration: 1))

}
```

That should work, but I have't tested it sorry.

**Update for Swift 3**

---

```
func centerOnNode(node: SKNode) {
    let cameraPositionInScene: CGPoint = node.scene!.convert(node.position, from: World)   
    node.parent!.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x:node.parent!.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x, y:node.parent!.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y), duration: 1))   
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example how to do it please?